# Aggregate list within list into one list

Tags: c#

I have those those definition

`ClassCountryCollection` is defined as:

```
public class ClassCountryCollection : KeyedCollection<string, ClassCountry>
    {
        protected override IEnumerable<string> GetKey(ClassCountry i)
        {
            return i.GetKey(i.Key);
        }
    }
```

`ClassCountry` is defined as

```
public class ClassCountry : ...
{
public string Key { get; set; }
public ClassCityCollection ClassCityList { get; set; }
...
}
```

`ClassCityCollection` is defined as:

```
public class ClassCityCollection : KeyedCollection<string, ClassCity>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(ClassCity i)
    {
        return i.Name;
    }
}
```

And, finally `ClassCity` is as:

```
public class ClassCity : ...
{
   public int Population { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
...
}
```

I have an object of type `ClassCountryCollection` `country`

```
1. Key=Spain, ClassCityCollection{{Population=55,Name=Barcelona},{Population=65,Name=Madrid}}
2. Key=Germany, ClassCityCollection{{Population=12,Name=Berlin},{Population=125,Name=Dresden}}
```

I want to create a list such that above thing becomes

```
1. {"Spain|Population=55,Name=Barcelona,Population=65,Name=Madrid"}
2. {"Germany|Population=12,Name=Berlin,Population=125,Name=Dresden"}
```

I tried

```
country.Select(x => new { x.ClassCityList.Select(w => string.Join(",",w.ToString().ToList())), x.Key }).ToList();
```

And then i got stuck, don't know how to continue. Maybe i create `ToString()` somewhere there to make it easier.

Comment: Your sample does not compile. Is class `KeyCollection` from standart library? I assume you meant `KeyedCollection`. Do you expect the resulting collection to be of type `IEnumerable<string>`? Please, provide minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Yeah, that is `KeyedCollection` . No need to be IENumerable. I can't reproduce this, cuz i juat grabbed this from big project. Defining everything to be reproducible will take dozen of pages

Comment: Do you want the result to be a collection of elements, where each element has two fields: first field - `string CountryName`, and the second field - `string Cities` delimited by commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed the class structure and return this code.

```
    namespace welcome
   {

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ClassCountryCollection cc = new ClassCountryCollection();

        var c1 = new ClassCountry()
        {
            Key = "Spain",
            ClassCityList = new ClassCityCollection{
                new ClassCity{Name ="Barcelona", Population = 55},
                new ClassCity{Name ="Madrid", Population = 65},
            }
        };

        var c2 = new ClassCountry()
        {
            Key = "Germany",
            ClassCityList = new ClassCityCollection{
                new ClassCity{Name ="Berlin", Population = 12},
                new ClassCity{Name ="Dresden", Population = 125},
            }
        };

        cc.Add(c1);
        cc.Add(c2);

        var g = cc.Select(x => x.Key + "|" + x.ClassCityList.Select(x => nameof(x.Population) + "=" + x.Population + "," + nameof(x.Name) + "=" + x.Name).Aggregate((d, s) => d + "," + s));
        foreach (var item in g)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ClassCountryCollection : KeyedCollection<string, ClassCountry>
{

    protected override string GetKeyForItem(ClassCountry item)
    {
        return item.Key;
    }

}
public class ClassCountry
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public ClassCityCollection ClassCityList { get; set; }
}

public class ClassCityCollection : KeyedCollection<string, ClassCity>
{
    protected override string GetKeyForItem(ClassCity i)
    {
        return i.Name;
    }
}


public class ClassCity
{
    public int Population { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
}
```

Code can be compiled and run to check the output.

Output is

```
  Spain|Population=55,Name=Barcelona,Population=65,Name=Madrid
  Germany|Population=12,Name=Berlin,Population=125,Name=Dresden
```

when ordered by key and then name 
output is

```
  Germany|Population=12,Name=Berlin,Population=125,Name=Dresden
  Spain|Population=55,Name=Barcelona,Population=65,Name=Madrid
```

Code need to modified as

```
  var g = cc.OrderBy(x=>x.Key).Select(x=>x.Key + "|" + x.ClassCityList.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).Select(x=>nameof(x.Population) +"=" + x.Population+","+nameof(x.Name) +"="+x.Name).Aggregate((d,s)=>d+","+s));
```

Comment: Thank you. I made slight changes and it perfectly suits my needs. Question was little off, so this is perfect for me. `cc.Select(x => x.Key + "|" + x.ClassCityList.Select(k => k.Name + "=" + k.Population).Aggregate((d, s) => d + "," + s)).ToList();` . One thing if you don't mind, how can i make sure that above list is ordered by x.Key, and then by k.Name?